# Font-size not changing inside specific media query

Tags: css

I have pasted my code below. The font sizes for one particular div (`.header > ul> li> a`) is not changing. The other divs are working properly. Please help

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:666px) {

  .header > ul> li> a{
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  .logo{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">
  <div style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-start;">
    <img src="/static/emblem.jpg" height="65" width="115" >
    <div class="logo" ></div>
    <div class="header" style="padding:0 0 0 15px">
      <ul  class="header_fields" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;padding:40px 0 0 0">
      <li><a href= "{% url 'login_new' %}" target="ifr" ONCLICK="setTitle1()" > Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'aboutus' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle2()"> <title>RCE-About</title>About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'products' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle3()" >Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle4()">Solutions</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'contacts' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle5()">Support</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It works fine (see my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xaduv36f/)), something else in your code must be the problem. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: where could the problem be then?

Comment: Since I do not have your full code I can't tell you. As I suggested, try to reproduce the problem on your own and produce a verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

The `@media` query tag was not closed off in the example provided. But your selectors could be simplified to select the hyperlinks like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:666px) {
  .header_fields li a {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  .logo {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">
  <div style="display:flex;justify-content:flex-start;">
    <img src="/static/emblem.jpg" height="65" width="115">

    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="header" style="padding:0 0 0 15px">

      <ul class="header_fields" style="display:flex;justify-content:center;padding:40px 0 0 0">
        <li><a href="{% url 'login_new' %}" target="ifr" ONCLICK="setTitle1()"> Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="{% url 'aboutus' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle2()">
            <title>RCE-About</title>About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'products' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle3()">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle4()">Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'contacts' %}" target="ifr" onclick="setTitle5()">Support</a></li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```